# How to append array of objects through form data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, form-data

I have dependents array, which has multiple objects. I need to send that array of  objects through form data. I have gone through so many tries but cannot get correct solution

```
    let dependents = [{name: "ashraf", number: 96546},{name: "himanshu", number: 98766}]
```

I was trying to append using

```
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("dependents[]", dependents)
```

Comment: Use dependents.concat(name of array to append), concat returns the new array.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Array#forEach to accomplish this... however your array elements will be stringified obejcts.

```js
const dependents = [{name: "ashraf", number: 96546},{name: "himanshu", number: 98766}]
const data = new FormData();
dependents.forEach(item => {
  data.append(`dependents[]`, JSON.stringify(item));
});
console.log(data.getAll('dependents[]'));
```