# React append array of objects to formdata

Tags: reactjs, multipartform-data, form-data

I have problem with appending array of objects (object contains file) to formdata.
Here is my formdata that I need to send to backend.

```
{
  education: {
    name: "naziv edukacije ovde celavi",
    company: 1,
    app: 1,
    category: 1
  },
  slides: [
    {
       serial_num: 1,
       text: "test slajda",
       image: File
    },
    {
       serial_num: 2,
       text: "text slajda 2",
       image: File
    }
  ]
}
```

It works fine for education object when I do

```
formData.append("education", education)
```

but slides just doesn't go through
[console.log of slides array before appending to formData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ceV.png)

I tried

```
formData.append("slides", slides)
```

which gives me [object Object], [object Object]

If i try

```
formData.append("slides", JSON.stringify(slides))
```

image key of object loses most of file data making it not enough for backend

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going to have to loop over your array as you append it to your formData, which I saw from a couple places, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604457/how-to-append-array-of-objects-through-form-data-in-javascript) & [here](https://hashnode.com/post/append-array-of-objects-to-formdata-cjg9yi4uv001ap8s2kmkq3gmt).

But for your example, you might be able to do something like this:

```
const slides = [{serial_num: 1, text: "test slajda", image: File}, {serial_num: 2, text: "text slajda 2", image: File}]
const formData = new FormData();
slides.forEach(item => {
  formData.append(`slides`, JSON.stringify(item));
});
console.log(formData.getAll('slides'));
```